# Excel not pulling correct value format from table for use in Match() formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of data imported through Power Query from a CSV.
I'm trying to lookup a separate identifier from a different table based on a column value from the import.

When I write my `Index( ,Match(), )` formula with reference to the cells from the imported table as the match source, I get `#N/A`. The evaluation steps show me that the cell value from the import table is a string literal (ie. `"76"`). The column and the table cells explicitly are "General" format as they are mixed numeric and alphanumeric (ie. `1`, `2`, `3`, `3A`, `3B`, etc.).

I've painted format between the import and lookup tables to make sure they're the same.

In my troubleshooting, I've also added 76 to a cell outside the imported table and directed my index-match formula to that cell as the match source (also format painted same as the tables). When using the cell outside the table, the reference pulls the value as `76` and finds a value in the lookup.

So, what about having my cell reference in the import table is making the reference value resolve to a string literal and causing my `match()` to fail?

PS. I'm using Index-Match, but the same issue seems to be happening if I orient my lookup table to an order suitable to VLookup.

Comment: As you seem to already understand, your imported data includes strings that only look like numbers, and your data you are using to look up is a mix of strings and actual numbers.  `MATCH` doesn't work with these mixed data types.  You also say _I've painted format between the import and lookup tables to make sure they're the same_  , Format doesn't change the underlying data, so that won't help. What you need to do is update one (or both) the data sets to the same data types.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I do understand that there are different types of data that can only reliably be represented as text. Your mention of format painter not doing much is well taken, thanks. What I'm not getting is that with those cells in both tables marked as general, Match still doesn't work. Editing the query, I see the assignment of the text data type to the column in question, but setting general or text on both tables after load doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: _What am I missing?_ cells can contain a only few different data types (numbers, strings, boolean TRUE/FALSE, errors eg #N/A or empty).  Cells also have a Format, (General, Text, Number, various Dates etc).  Applying a formt changes how a cell is displayed, but does not change its data type.  The confusion here is that a cell containing a string that looks like a number is still a string and does not equal a cell that contains an actual number.

Comment: [Here's one resource that talks about resolving this issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885#:~:text=Use%20Paste%20Special%20and%20Multiply&text=Select%20the%20cells%20that%20have,converts%20the%20text%20to%20numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but to force MATCH to match numbers with strings, you can try appending double quotes at the end of both the lookup_value and lookup_array like so:

```
=MATCH(D1&"",A1:A5&"",0)
```

Confirmed with **ctrl+shift+enter**, because appending the "" to the array makes this an array formula.

[image]

As you can see, the "2" in the A column is a string (="2") but the 2 in the D column is a number. By appending "" both to the lookup value and array, excel will convert both of these into strings and match the 2 correctly.